# Why am I getting these random wires in simple 4 cube cut in a large cube, nothing should be overlapping

Tags: bevel, lines

I am just doing a basic boolean cut of small cube mirrored across x,y axis (4 cuts) in a larger cube.
I can't bevel it afterwards. Why am I getting these additional lines there?

[image]

[image]
Ultimately I would want to get 3d box insert that looks like this (but beveled a little, no sharp edges):
[image]

Comment: Blender faces don't support un-connected holes, and the automated Boolean fix  for that doesn't know how to find the most 'desirable' connection, which will vary  from case to case. If the cavities here don't need to be procedural (to be animated, for example), there's no need for a Boolean.

Comment: boolean ops are never basic, but just unpredictable depending on what you want to do after that.

Comment: hmm, so what would be a better way to cut these holes so I can bevel them on all sharp edges of the entire cube with holes?

Comment: I think you already have an answer for that. If it's not enough described for your needs, ask in comments.

Comment: For your second question, the boolean is a good solution in that case, maybe use a sphere with less vertices to make the corrections easier

Comment: @mrblender007 I have a pure-modelling method, but there are quite a few steps, (Maybe just as easy to clean up after a Boolean) Will post when I can. Further to moonboots suggestion, I think you may find a Round Cube giives you a better match, either way, than a UV Sphere.

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines?

- Subdivide
- <kbd>I</kbd> Inset all
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> Bevel cross-bars
- <kbd>E</kbd> extrude panes

[image]

.. followed by an <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> extrusion downward of the perimeter,  <kbd>F</kbd> to fill, and maybe another inset of the bottom.

[image]

Comment: difference between explained and unexplained answer... +1

Comment: will that method allow me to also cut half of a sphere in the middle of the cross and bevel all sharp edges in the model?

Comment: Hi, @mrblender007.. please illustrate in your original question where you would like this half-sphere cavity to be .. :)

Comment: @RobinBetts added to original question

Comment: @RobinBetts also, the way I attempted to do this with boolean difference, it is not possible to easily clean that up and bevel still?

Comment: @lemon isn't his name Robin Bestt?

Comment: @moonboots ... I'm staying out of this one, if you don't mind :)

Comment: @Robin Betts I agree that my answer was lazy but the initial question was a bit vague so you never know how accurate you need to be   ;)

Answer (score 1):

Booleans often give bad topology, therefore the difficulty to bevel. You need to correct the topology or start your shape from scratch with another method (your shape is rather easy and doesn't need any boolean actually). As for the edges that you are showing, you can't cut a hole without connecting the inner edge loop to the outer edge loop.

For the shape, create these edge loops with some <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>:

[image]

Then extrude down:

[image]

Comment: ctrl+r doesn't do anything, and btw would that method also work for cutting out half of a sphere in that box?

Comment: @mrblender007: I am sorry to say but asking for "additional" things you didn't ask in your question isn't fair and shouldn't be done. Concentrate only on your question asked. If you have additional question, please open a new post. thx.

Comment: @mrblender007 Ctrl+R might not do anything on your object since it can only work with quads, but here it is shown how you should build the object new from scratch. And why your object is problemstic for beveling I explained in my answer to your first question which you seem to ignore.